# SQLite "Order by" in query gives wrong order

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table with 3 columns: name, date and time being String, String and Double respectively. I want to order the table according to the values of the last columns, but if i have in my database the times of:
1230
800
900
The order I get is 
900
800
1230

This is the method I use to order it:

```
public List<Register> orderAllRegisters() {
    List<Register> registers = new LinkedList<Register>();

    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_REGISTERS + " ORDER BY " + RKEY_TIME + " DESC";

    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sortOrder =
            RKEY_TIME;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    // 3. go over each row, build register and add it to list
    Register register = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            register = new Register();
            register.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            register.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            register.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
            register.setTime(cursor.getDouble(3));

            // Add register to registers
            registers.add(register);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("resultado", registers.toString());

    // return registers
    return registers;
}
```

This is how the table is created:

```
String CREATE_REGISTER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE registers ( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "name TEXT, "+
            "date TEXT, "+
            "time REAL)";
```

db.execSQL(CREATE_REGISTER_TABLE);

Oh and: 
private static final String TABLE_REGISTERS = "registers";

To add something to the database i use:

```
public void addRegister(Register register){
    Log.d("addRegister", register.toString());
    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(RKEY_NAME, register.getName()); // get name
    values.put(RKEY_DATE, register.getDate());
    values.put(RKEY_TIME, register.getTime());
    // 3. insert
    db.insert(TABLE_REGISTERS, // table
            null, //nullColumnHack
            values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = column values

    // 4. close
    db.close();
}
```

I have tried changing the column "time" to int and strings to see if that was the problem but I also get wrong orders.
I also tried putting DOUBLE and INT instead of REAL on the CREATE_TABLE_REGISTER definition but that didn't work either.

If there is any other info that would be useful to solve this case i'd be happy to give.
I would be grateful for any help!

Edit:
Here's the Register Class:

```
public class Register {
private int id;
private String name;
private String date;
private double time;

public Register(){}

public Register(String name, String date, double time) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Register [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", date=" + date +", time="+ time + "]";
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public double getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(double time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

}

Comment: What is `register.getTime()` returning?

Comment: The order you describe is consistent with the values being stored as strings, not reals. Though if inserting a string holding a number into a real column it should be getting converted (see https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html )... hmm.

Comment: Anyways, I'd suggest combining your date and time columns into a single one (Both in the program and in the database), either a NUMERIC column holding the timestamp in unix epoch or julian date, or a TEXT column holding it in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format or another one supported by [sqlite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). It's a lot more flexible, and as well as simpler to properly order timestamps from multiple dates.

Comment: Hi Shawn thanks for your comment! I figured they were being ordered as Strings but I don't know why. I thought I was storing them as Double values. I can't really combine the columns and use a timestamp because I am actually receiving these numbers through bluetooth from an embedded device, they are actually ammount of miliseconds. I will edit the question so it includes my Register Class. register.getTime() returns a Double value.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was really silly. The code was right but because i had first generated the database putting the "time" value in a TEXT column it didn't change the values that were already there. All I had to do was uninstall the app and generate another database with the new code. Thanks for the insight in the comments!